# Trying to add a "highest date" criteria in the middle of an IF formula

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, max

I am writing a formula right now, and hit a bit of a snag.

Here is the base formula: `=IF(B:B=J2,IF(A:A=L2,IF(E:E>0,C:C))))`

What my formula is doing is match the phone number(B:B=J2) and the camp(A:A=L2) to find the employee number(C:C) that sold it as long as the payment amount is above zero(E:E>0).

I also want to make sure it is only giving me the employee number that sold it the most recently, so having the highest value in the D:D column.

[picture of my workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIr5T.png)

I tried to add an If statement that was MAX(IF(S:S) in the middle of the formula but I knew that wasnt right and it didn't work. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that I should actually be using an xlookup function for this. BAsed on the data above, this formula helped me achieve my results.

```
=XLOOKUP(MAX(D:D),(B:B=J2)*(A:A=L2)*D:D,C:C,,-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(r,A2:E23,
INDEX(
      SORT(FILTER(r,(INDEX(r,,1)=L2)*(INDEX(r,,2)=J2)*(INDEX(r,,5)>0)),
           4,
           -1),
      1,
      3))
```

The filter spills all values meeting the conditions. Sorting it by the date-column largest to smallest, and taking the 1st row, third column from that indexed range shows the result.